# Given that $x,y,z\in\mathbb C$ satisfy $x^2+xy+y^2=1+i, y^2+yz+z^2=-2, z^2+zx+x^2=1$ Find $3(xy+yz+zx)^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

> Given that $x,y,z\in\mathbb C$ satisfy $$x^2+xy+y^2=1+i, y^2+yz+z^2=-2, z^2+zx+x^2=1$$ Find $3(xy+yz+zx)^2$

**Attempt:**

$x^2+2xy+y^2=1+i+xy$

$y^2+2yz+z^2=-2+yz$

$z^2+2zx+x^2=1+zx$

Adding, $(x+y)^2+(y+z)^2+(z+x)^2=i+xy+yz+zx$

Not able to proceed from here.

Or, maybe it can be written as

$2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+(xy+yz+zx)=i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract given equations two at a time, you will get following 3 equations.
$$(x-y)(x+y+z)=3$$
$$(y-z)(x+y+z)=i$$
$$(z-x)(x+y+z)=-3-i$$

Square and add these three equations.
$$(x+y+z)^2((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2)=9-1+9-1+6i$$

Assume $x^2+y^2+z^2=a$ and $xy+yz+zx=b$, so
$$(a+2b)(2a-2b)=16+6i ..............(1)$$

From you last line
$$2a+b=i$$
so $a=\frac{i-b}{2}$, substitute it in (1)

$$(\frac{i+3b}{2})(\frac{i-3b}{2})=8+3i$$

From here it can be solved for $3b^2=-11-4i$

Answer (score 2):

A funny thing is that a bit of geometric intuition goes a long way. Bear with me.

So, let's first treat a special case where $x,y,z$ are all *real and positive*. Draw a point $O$ in the plane and three rays out of it at angles $120^\circ$. Let $A, B, C$ be the points on those rays such that $|OA|=x, |OB|=y, |OC|=z$. Let, $|BC|=a, |CA|=b, |AB|=c$.

[image]

Now the cosine theorem tells us that:

$$c^2=|AB|^2=|OA|^2+|OB|^2-2|OA||OB|\cos(120^\circ)=x^2+xy+y^2$$

Similarly:

$$a^2=y^2+yz+z^2$$
$$b^2=z^2+zx+x^2$$

Now we have a geometric interpretation for the terms $x^2+xy+y^2$, $y^2+yz+z^2$ and $z^2+zx+x^2$ - these are just the squares of the sides of $\triangle ABC$.

What can we say about $xy+yz+zx$? We will see that it is very closely related to the *area* of $\triangle ABC$. Notice that the area of $\triangle OAB$ is $\frac{1}{2}|OA||OB|\sin(120^\circ)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}xy$. Similarly, the area of $\triangle OBC$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}yz$ and the area of $\triangle OCA$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}zx$. Thus, the total area of the triangle $\triangle ABC$ is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}(xy+yz+zx)$.

To connect the two, recall [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), which expresses the area of the triangle in terms of its sides: $\mathcal A(\triangle ABC)=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ where $s$ is the semi-perimeter: $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. Putting together what we know, we get:

$$3(xy+yz+xz)^2=16\mathcal A(\triangle ABC)^2=16s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$$

where we can now multiply across the right side:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}16s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)&=&(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)\\&=&(b^2+2bc+c^2-a^2)(a^2-b^2+2bc-c^2)\\&=&4b^2c^2-(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2\\&=&-b^4-c^4-a^4+2b^2c^2+2a^2c^2+2a^2b^2\end{array}$$

In other words, we have expressed $3(xy+yz+xz)^2$ as a function of $X=a^2=y^2+yz+z^2$, $Y=b^2=z^2+zx+x^2$ and $Z=c^2=x^2+xy+y^2$:

$$3(xy+yz+zx)^2=-X^2-Y^2-Z^2+2XY+2YZ+2XZ$$

---

So far we know that the above identity is true for $x,y,z$ real and positive. Now we will *extrapolate* and say that the above identity should be true for any complex numbers $x,y,z\in\mathbb C$. This is actually true as well, and there are multiple ways of proving that:

1. Treat the entire story above just as a motivation. Calculate both sides (brute force) and see that they are equal.
2. Same as above, but leave the hard work to some AI (e.g. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3%28xy%2Byz%2Bzx%29%5E2%3D-%28x%5E2%2Bxy%2By%5E2%29%5E2-%28y%5E2%2Byz%2Bz%5E2%29%5E2-%28z%5E2%2Bzx%2Bx%5E2%29%5E2%2B2%28x%5E2%2Bxy%2By%5E2%29%28y%5E2%2Byz%2Bz%5E2%29%2B2%28y%5E2%2Byz%2Bz%5E2%29%28z%5E2%2Bzx%2Bx%5E2%29%2B2%28z%5E2%2Bzx%2Bx%5E2%29%28x%5E2%2Bxy%2By%5E2%29)).
3. Use some algebraic considerations, see **Note** below.

Now all you need to do is substitute $X=-2, Y=1, Z=1+i$ in the above formula and this will give you the value of $3(xy+yz+zx)^2$:

$$\begin{array}{cl}&3(xy+yz+zx)^2\\=&-X^2-Y^2-Z^2+2XY+2YZ+2XZ\\=&-(-2)^2-1^2-(1+i)^2+2(-2)\cdot 1+2\cdot 1\cdot(1+i)+2(1+i)(-2)\\=&-11-4i\end{array}$$

---

**Note**: One way of algebraic reasoning for the point 3 above would be this: the polynomial of three complex variables $LHS-RHS$, which is

$$P(x,y,z)=3(xy+yz+zx)^2-(-X^2-Y^2-Z^2+2XY+2YZ+2ZX)$$

(with $X, Y, Z$ appropriately substituted) vanishes for $x,y,z$ real and positive. Why does it vanish on the entire $x,y,z\in\mathbb C$? In fact, this is true for any polynomial over complex numbers:

**Lemma**: If a polynomial $P(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ with complex coefficients is zero for all $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ real and positive, it is a zero polynomial.

**Proof**: use induction on $n$:

$n=0$: $P$ has no variables and it vanishes, so it is a constant $0$.

$n\to n+1$: express $P$ as a polynomial in $x_{n+1}$ with coefficients being polynomials in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}P(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})&=&Q_0(x_1,\ldots, x_n)\\&+&Q_1(x_1,\ldots, x_n)x_{n+1}\\&+&Q_2(x_1,\ldots, x_n)x_{n+1}^2\\&+&\ldots\\&+&Q_k(x_1,\ldots, x_n)x_{n+1}^k\end{array}$$

where $k$ is the highest degree of $x_{n+1}$ in $P$. For any fixed $x_1,\ldots x_n$ real and positive, this turns into a polynomial in only one variable $x_{n+1}$ and it vanishes for all $x_{n+1}$ real and positive, i.e. infinitely many points. Thus, a polynomial of finite degree $k$ has infinitely many zeros, so it must be a zero polynomial. In turn it means that all $Q_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ vanish for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ real and positive. Thus, per inductive hypothesis, they are all zero polynomials. Thus, $P$ is a zero polynomial.$\,\blacksquare$

Comment: As an aside, for the lemma, we can weaken the condition to be "zero on a lattice with sufficiently many points" (depending on the degree of the polynomial). Proof via combinatorial nullstellensatz.